# Can circle be converted into oval using radius in Canvas

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-canvas

I have following code:

```
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius , colorRed);
```

I am trying to draw a similar circle below it to make an oval i am doing this and have tried other things too but its not working:

```
RectF ovalBounds = new RectF();
ovalBounds.set(x, radius, y, radius);
canvas.drawOval(ovalBounds, pOuterBullsEye);
```

Here is in an image what i am trying to achieve. 
[image]

I am not sure how to get bottomY value correctly.

Comment: @greg-449 - yes i am using it in android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear what you are trying to do but one mistake is that you need to change the set call:

```
ovalBounds.set(x, y, x + 2 * radius, y + 2 * radius);
```